# how to add custom block to specific product type view pages in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have created custom block.
I want to show this block only in grouped product pages.

any one have idea the syntax for magento2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use product type dependent layout updates catalog_product_view_type_{prodyct_type}.xml (catalog_product_view_type_ grouped.xml)

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
 <referenceContainer name="content">
     <block class="..." />
 </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```